# Can MTM 2012 be used to run manual tests on a Windows XP machine?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I know that Visual Studio Test Professional cannot be installed on XP and it uses .NET 4.5, but does anyone know if it is possible to separately install and use the Test Runner component on an XP machine to run manual tests?  I've been scouring the MS site and have not been able to find an answer, although I see references to running *test agents* on XP machines.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do so as part of a Lab Environment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518930.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MTM to launch test runner, test runner cannot be separately installed. To install MTM 2012, you need Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Visual Studio 2012 Premium, or Test Professional 2012, none of them can be installed on windows XP machine.

"test agent" component which is used to run automated tests on a multi-machine environment and that component is supported on windows xp.

For more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US